# How to target Android versions LESS THAN a certain build

Tags: android, android-build

Android has gone and deprecated the Health Device Profile on Android 10. This is an important profile to use if one wants to have reliable Bluetooth medical devices. Android says use BLE not realizing how bad their own BLE implementation is, topped off with the fact that Medical devices following the low energy profiles (which are poorly specified) result in buggy and unreliable communications and are a major headache (Android's implementation of HDP was also poor because they didn't understand the profile - but we have managed to work around most of those and at least they are more consistent from platform to platform than the BLE!).

Now that they have deprecated it in 10 I get build complaints. Mainly this complaint:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
```

It turns out when using the  `gradlew.bat build --warning-mode=all --stacktrace`

to find out the cause that it is the HDP profile APIs causing this error. I would like to be able to target the Health Device Profile APIs UP TO 9 but exclude all those above so I don't get this build complaint. My minimum version takes care of the lower boundary. Is there a way to target certain APIs just to 9 and less?

My guess is no. It seems all their options are version X+ and never X-

Comment: "it is the HDP profile APIs causing this error" -- um, are you sure? HDP profile APIs are not implemented as Gradle tasks AFAIK, and that error is referring to issues with Gradle tasks and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
// Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // Do What you want
    }
```

More details on [Targeting specific build versions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms#java).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have been doing stuff like that for quite a while, but I don't think it will stop those incompatibility errors. I was looking for something that would do the equivalent but for a class or method (in this case a class). Like @Target(build). I do the reverse to avoid problems with methods/classes that only support build X+. I need something for X-